# Powershell won't output "£" in email html body

Tags: powershell

I have the following code, which counts the number of PDFs in specific folders, and counts the number of sheets in those specific PDFs, and sends an email with this data.

I've anonymised part of the script.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

#This gets the number of PDF files in the Archive folder, this shows the successful uploads to Portal.
$Archive = $($compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)    
@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Archive\*.*" -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate}).Count)

#This gets the number of PDF files in the Exception folder, this shows the failed uploads to Portal.
$Exception = $($compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)    
@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Exception\*.*" -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate}).Count)

#This gets the number of pages in all PDF files succsssfully upoaded to Portal.
$folder = $($compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)    
@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Archive\*.*" -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate}))

$Count = $Files = 0

foreach($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.pdf)){
    $Pages = (C:\PS_Scripts\xpdf-tools-win-4.02\xpdf-tools-win-4.02\bin64\pdfinfo.exe $File.FullName | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Pages:\s*)\d+').Matches.Value
    $Count += $Pages
    $Files++}
$Count

#This calculates the saving on sheets of paper, not including ink and printers. Each ream of 500 sheets costs us £1.98. So a single sheet costs 0.4 pence
$Saving = (($Count*0.4)/100)

#This converts the number to £nn.nn
$Pounds = '{0:C}' -f $Saving
$Pounds

#This gets Mondays Date
$Friday=  (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')  

#This gets Sundays Date
$Thursday= (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')  

#This begins the email  
$recipients = "user1 <user1@email.com>"

send-mailmessage -from "emailtest@email.com" `
            -to $recipients `
            -Subject "Weekly Data" `
            -body "Hi all,
            <br />
            <br />
            Please find below the weekly stats for Reports going to Portal. 
            <br />
            <br />
            From Friday to Thursday ($Friday- $Thursday), there were $Archive successful automated reports sent to Portal.
            <br />
            <br />
            This saved us printing, and scanning $Count pages of paper.
            <br />
            <br />
            This amounts to roughly $Pounds in savings during this period on paper alone!
            <br />
            <br />
            Also, during this same period, there were $Exception failed reports sent to Portal, these have either been rectified or will be rectified imminently.
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />"`
            -BodyAsHtml `
            -priority  Normal `
            -dno onSuccess, onFailure `
            -smtpServer  egat@email.com

Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

My issue is specifically with $Pounds, it does everything i want it to do. It ouputs the calculaton in the following format,
£nn.nn, example: £45.52
I have confirmed this, as within Powershell ISE I return the value of $Pounds to check it works.

But when i receive the email, the £ sign is replaced with a "?", see email copy below,

> Hi all,
>
> Please find below the weekly stats for Reports going to Portal.
>
> From Monday to Sunday (01/05/2020 - 07/05/2020) last week, there were 235 successful automated reports sent to Portal.
>
> This saved us printing, and scanning 1256 pages of paper.
>
> This amounts to roughly ?5.02 in savings during this period on paper alone!
>
> Also, during this same period, there were 0 failed reports sent to Portal, these have either been rectified or will be rectified imminently.

Why does it not display £5.02?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Uhuj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'Html Entify' the Pound sign using the [HttpUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility) class in `System.Web`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$Pound = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode('£123.456')
```

outputs

```
&#163;123.456
```

which in HTML shows

```
£123.456
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a HTML encoding issue. I think you need to either use the following code.

```bsh
# Instead of converting to Pounds, round down to two decimal places
$pounds = [math]::Round($Saving,2)

# html
"This amounts to roughly &pound;$Pounds in savings during this period on paper alone!"
```

Or possibly, unable to test, add `-Encoding [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` to [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7)

#### EDIT

Difference between default and UTF8 Encoding. Your email program is probably in UTF8 and `163` on it's own is not a displayable character.

```bsh
$Pound = "£"
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$enc.GetBytes($Pound)
194
163
$def = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
$def.GetBytes($Pound)
163
```

Go with the first option.

Comment: Thank you Ash, i got it working now. Much appreciated.